# Flutter firebase_auth hassle with deprecated code (From 0.16 to 1.0)

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, flutter-dependencies, deprecated

I post this after some time of research and not managing to find anything myself.

So...I have a wrapper class called **FirebaseAuthService** and after upgrading the firebase_auth package I have some errors.

```
class FirebaseAuthService {
  final _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  User _userFromFirebase(User user) {
    return user == null ? null : User(uid: user.uid);
  }

  Stream<User> get onAuthStateChanged {
    return _firebaseAuth.onAuthStateChanged.map(_userFromFirebase);
  }

  Future<User> signInAnonymously() async {
    final authResult = await _firebaseAuth.signInAnonymously();
    return _userFromFirebase(authResult.user);
  }

  Future<void> signOut() async {
    return await _firebaseAuth.signOut();
  }
}
```

[FirebaseAuthService Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5qPs.png)

I need the FirebaseAuthService in the auth_widget_builder class

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('AuthWidgetBuilder rebuild');
    final authService =
        Provider.of<FirebaseAuthService>(context, listen: false);
    return StreamBuilder<User>(
      stream: authService.onAuthStateChanged,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        print('StreamBuilder: ${snapshot.connectionState}');
```

[AuthWidgetBuilder Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ucxlw.png)

[Problems Text Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0ZoK.png)

I have read that onAuthStateChanged is deprecated and I should use onAuthStateChanges but still not working, I have read on another post that .map() is deprecated. another error on _userFromFirebase(authResult.user). I don't know from where to grasp the problem...   Here is the repository from the project that I want to modify and use: **https://github.com/bizz84/firebase_user_avatar_flutter** If anyone manages to help me, I could not thank enough...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call the function`authStateChanges` in your `FirebaseAuthService` class like this. Like this:

```
   Stream<User> get user {
        return _auth.authStateChanges().map(_userFromFirebaseUser);
      }
```

Comment: Hello and thank you, I think I saw this answer somewhere else... I don't have a variable _auth, you may be referring to _firebaseAuth. Now I have an error inside the map(_userFromFirebase).

Comment: Firebase has a class User defined already.
`class MyUser{
final String uid;
MyUser(this.uid);
}`
`class FirebaseAuthService {
  final _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  MyUser _userFromFirebase(User user) {
    return user == null ? null : MyUser(uid: user.uid);
  }

  Stream<MyUser> get onAuthStateChanged {
    return _firebaseAuth.onAuthStateChanged.map(_userFromFirebase);
  }

  Future<MyUser> signInAnonymously() async {
    final authResult = await _firebaseAuth.signInAnonymously();
    return _userFromFirebase(authResult.user);
  }`

Comment: Hello, we almost got it working, there is still a bug in this line...
Stream<MyUser> get onAuthStateChanged {
    return _firebaseAuth.onAuthStateChange.map(_userFromFirebase);
  }
The getter 'onAuthStateChange' isn't defined for the type 'FirebaseAuth'.

Comment: I modified it to return _firebaseAuth.authStateChanges().map(_userFromFirebase);
Hope it still works hah.

Comment: Error on build....
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'E:\development\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cloud_firestore-1.0.3\android\build.gradle' line: 54

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':cloud_firestore'.
> Could not find method platform() for arguments [com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.2.0] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

Answer (score 0):

**USE THIS CODE:**

```dart
Stream <UserModel.User> get user {  
  return _auth.authStateChanges()
         .asyncMap(_userFromUser)
         .where((user) => user != null)
         .map((user) => user!);
}
```